# any way to check if js var has a method or not?

Tags: javascript

I got this error when calling

```
  if (! !!javaRest.cookie.get('token'))
    return javaRest.cookie.get('token').length >4;
  else
    return false;
```

and got this error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Now I want to know if there is anyway I can know if my js object variable got a length variable or not.

Comment: Its not that your variable doesnt have a length but at this stage your variable is undefined.  ie `javaRest.cookie.get('token')` is undefined

Comment: it is undefined, so it can't have a length variable. I assume the cookie "token" does not exist. Also, why are there 3 `!`'s ?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is not that `.length` is undefined, it's that `javaRest.cookie.get('token')` is, hence the error of `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

I would try this, instead:

```
var token = javaRest.cookie.get('token');
return (token && token.length > 4);
```

The above completely replaces your `if`-based code.  Note that this also adheres to the *Don't Repeat Yourself* principle, with the temporary variable avoiding a second set of property lookups and a function call.

Comment: thanks, after seeing your code I felt like stupid. I looks rally good, but I don't know why it did not work :/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your logic is incorrect:

```
if (! !!javaRest.cookie.get('token'))  // cast to inverse boolean
// should be
if (!!javaRest.cookie.get('token'))    // cast to boolean
```

Do you want to negate the result of that?

```
!!! undefined // true
!! undefined  // false
```

You're trying to get `.length` of `undefined` (as your error says).